# Android GeoCoder: search by zip code returns unexpected results

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to search with a user input text via Android`s GeoCoder class. Here is my code:

```
Geocoder iGeocoder = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.GERMAN);

public Address getAdress(String aUserInput) {
    List<Address> tAddressList = iGeocoder.getFromLocationName(aUserInput, 1000, 47.060940, 8.564278, 51.526396, 13.736392);
    if(tAddressList != null &&
                tAddressList.size() > 0) {
        for(Address tAddress : tAddressList) {

            // return the first adress found for germany.
            Log.e(TAG, "returning Adress: " + tAddress );
            if(tAddress.getCountryCode().equals("DE")) {

                return tAddress;
            }

        }
        return null;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The bounding box I pass to the `getFromLocationName` roughly represents the german state Bayern. I know that this bounding box doesn´t guarantee that the result address is really there. I found some problems especially when searching via ZIP Code.

- Some result addresses returned when searching by zip code don´t have a "admin area", hence I can´t filter for my desired state (="Bayern").
- Oddly enough if I search for the zip codes 97070, 97078 or 97076, the GeoCoder only returns addresses in Oregon, USA. However these zip codes are also places in the german town of Würzburg. E.g. 97082 will return Würzburg Address, however 97070 (Würzburg central) will not be found, it only returns Oregon addresses.

Comment: That is the code. It´s all done in the one line "getFromLocationName..". Are you missing something?

Comment: The number of results (1000) and the boundary coordinates are static, the "aUserInput" is what the user is searching for, it can be anything from zip codes to city or street names even point of interests.

Comment: thank you so much for your time!

Comment: You just made a Typo. Check my answer below

Comment: @YvetteColomb Was trying to minimize the error as [android developper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#Geocoder(android.content.Context,%20java.util.Locale)) said second argument is  `the desired Locale for the query results`. I don't think OP failed using the doc. I guessed it was either confusion about `locale` or `typo`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try customising your [locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html). Using GERMANY and GERMAN. [Germany](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#GERMANY) is used for the locale of Germany the country as opposed to the [language](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#GERMAN).

```
Locale locale = new Locale(langCode, countryCode) 

Locale locale = new Locale("de", "DE");

Geocoder iGeocoder = new Geocoder(getContext(), locale);
```

GeoCode is defaulted to the US, so it appears it's filtering on the search of the postcode first. If you [test here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro):

`97070` gives the result for [Wilsonville, OR 97070, USA](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=97070)

`47.060940, 8.564278` gives [Spitzibüelstrasse 8, 6410 Goldau, Switzerland](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&latlng=47.06094,8.564278)

`97070, 47.060940, 8.564278` gives no results (this is just  tester), it can't differentiate the results to include that postcode and the lat long.

If you need to increase the locale area - you can always create an array of 3 country locales and search on each.

You also have too many returns - you only need the one `null` return after the first `if` and if it doesn't return an address, to ensure all paths have a return value.

```
public Address getAdress(String aUserInput) {
    .../...
    if(.../...) {
        for(Address tAddress : tAddressList) {
            .../...
            if(tAddress.getCountryCode().equals("DE")) {

                return tAddress;
            }
        }
     }
    return null;
}
```

There's also **[Region Biasing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#RegionCodes)** *Thanks to [jausen brett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5540231/jausen-brett) for the link*

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=<some address>&region=de&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

and **[Component Filtering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering)**

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=locality:<desired locality>|country:DE&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Comment: Well elaborate .

Comment: Since you were in moderator election I think you'll be reasonable enough... People are downvoting my answer which is right (a shortcut to yours) OP just made a typo. Feel like friends are ganging up on me (coding doesn't lie... both your answer and mine fix the issue and I got TWO down votes. Conspiracy ? lol)

Comment: @YvetteColomb Exactly. Since you where on mod election I know I can trust you. That's why I even posted. First answer did not solve Ok. Second answer does not deserve a downvote. OP just misused a Java constant. You went deeper. If OP knew it was just a typo he'd have never ask the question. So with you vote up, I guess OP downvoted me too. I'll remove my answer since it's not helpfull to know it's a typo mistake

Comment: Google API doc has another example of filtering by region ("biasing geocoding results") . Though in this case city name is used, I would expect same behavior for any address component.

Comment: [Google API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#RegionCodes) However, this is an example using GET request. From my understanding, postcode should also work as address.

Comment: I just tested it (sorry about the delay). 97070 returns expected Würzburg address now. Thank you very much.